# Wget or similar for Android

Tags: android, curl, https, wget

I need to make petitions against a https server and download data that the server sends back (text, video files or image files), inside my Android app.

It works fine in the terminal of suse Linux and wget or curl. Request have this structure:

```
wget --post-data "token=xxxx&option1=1&option2=4&File=video" https://api.serverx.com/ --no-check-certificate
```

My question is if there is any wget or similar working in Android, or how can I make this kind of petitions in another way.

I read about implement wget in the NDK but I'd like to know your experience or recomendations.
Thanks

## Solution

Using NDK to port Wget was too complicated.
After some research I found a solution using DefaultHttpClient and adding a couple of classes to avoid checking the certificates. I follow [this article](http://www.virtualzone.de/2011-02-27/how-to-use-apache-httpclient-with-httpsssl-on-android)

```
SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", new EasySSLSocketFactory(), 443));

    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    params.setParameter(ConnManagerPNames.MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS, 30);
    params.setParameter(ConnManagerPNames.MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_ROUTE, new ConnPerRouteBean(30));
    params.setParameter(HttpProtocolParams.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
    HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    ClientConnectionManager cm = new SingleClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);
```

Comment: Here is a page that has wget for android http://hoffman-andrews.com/android/wget/ there is also a few github projects that have ported wget to android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using wget or ndk for that is a bad idea : go directly `java` and use `HttpClient` to craft a post request : example can be found [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient).

The response will contain your data, ready to be saved to a file.

Additionally, you can put it in an asynch task, progress monitoring : forking an external process like Curl ou wget should be kept as last chance (that communicating with a server is clearly not)

Comment: I will have a look to this solution. Also I try with **HttpsURLConnection**